# Django Channels Error: No route found for path 'socketcluster/'. (I dont have any route called 'socketcluster/')

Tags: python, django, django-channels

I'm learning Django Channels and I keep getting this error randomly:

```
[Failure instance: Traceback: <class 'ValueError'>: No route found for path 'socketcluster/'.
C:\Users\Alvaro\.virtualenvs\DjangoChannels-lIBZLoxz\lib\site-packages\autobahn\websocket\protocol.py:2839:processHandshake
C:\Users\Alvaro\.virtualenvs\DjangoChannels-lIBZLoxz\lib\site-packages\txaio\tx.py:366:as_future
C:\Users\Alvaro\.virtualenvs\DjangoChannels-lIBZLoxz\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py:151:maybeDeferred
C:\Users\Alvaro\.virtualenvs\DjangoChannels-lIBZLoxz\lib\site-packages\daphne\ws_protocol.py:72:onConnect
--- <exception caught here> ---
C:\Users\Alvaro\.virtualenvs\DjangoChannels-lIBZLoxz\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py:151:maybeDeferred
C:\Users\Alvaro\.virtualenvs\DjangoChannels-lIBZLoxz\lib\site-packages\daphne\server.py:200:create_application
C:\Users\Alvaro\.virtualenvs\DjangoChannels-lIBZLoxz\lib\site-packages\channels\staticfiles.py:41:__call__
C:\Users\Alvaro\.virtualenvs\DjangoChannels-lIBZLoxz\lib\site-packages\channels\routing.py:54:__call__
C:\Users\Alvaro\.virtualenvs\DjangoChannels-lIBZLoxz\lib\site-packages\channels\routing.py:150:__call__
]
WebSocket DISCONNECT /socketcluster/ [127.0.0.1:58432]
```

My client application is a very simple HTML Page with Javascript that connects to the server and that sends a message when a button is clicked.

```
// Connect Socket
const endpoint = 'ws://localhost:8000/test/'
const socket = new WebSocket(endpoint)

// Button Event listener
const btn = document.getElementById('myBtn')
btn.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    socket.send("Button Clicked!!!!")
})
```

My consumer is very simple, only accepts connections and prints them as well as the messages and disconnections:

```
from channels.consumer import AsyncConsumer

class MyConsumer(AsyncConsumer):
    async def websocket_connect(self, event):
        # Runs when new client tries to connect
        print("Connected:", event)
        await self.send({"type": "websocket.accept"})

    async def websocket_receive(self, event):
        # Runs when new message received
        print("Received:", event)

    async def websocket_disconnect(self, event):
        # Runs when client gets disconnected
        print("Disconnected:", event)
```

Finally, I only have 1 route called "test/" inside my "routing.py":

```
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from django.urls import path
from apps.core.consumers import MyConsumer


router = URLRouter([
    path("test/", MyConsumer)
])


application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    'websocket': router
})
```

Everything else seems to work fine, when I click the HTML button I receive the message in my server but this error message keeps showing up every 20-60 seconds or so.

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue have you resolved it?

Comment: Seems like I get it with a simple Django project also, it shows up randomly and restarting the computer seems to help. @JoeG

Comment: You ever figure this one out?